# letter spacing in jsPDF with .text() method

Tags: javascript, jspdf

How do I specify letter spacing to text in jsPDF .text() method? This is the code I use now.

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [183, 203]);
doc.setFontSize(9);
doc.setFont("monospace");
doc.text(39, 38, 'hello world');
doc.output('dataurl');
```

Answer (score 2):

this will change the letter spacing of the entire pdf
pdf.setCharSpace(5);
5 is the space that you give to the entire pdf, if you want to apply it only to a specific text it would be
pdf.text('text', 30, 105, { charSpace: 5 });

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [jspdf.js](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/jspdf.js), you can use `lstext` function to specify letter spacing.

```
API.lstext = function (text, x, y, spacing) {
    for (var i = 0, len = text.length; i < len; i++, x += spacing) this.text(text[i], x, y);
};
```

Usage should be,

```
doc.lstext('Hello World', 39, 38, 5);
```

Comment: nice.. it does not support further arguments like 'center'.. time for a bug report.